# how to return I-94?

Tags: usa, working-visas, canadian-citizens

I'm Canadian and was working US from 2015 till 2018 on TN visa.

I got paper I-94 when I crossed border in September 2015.

I left US July 31 2018 and my TN expired September 18.

But I still have I-94 in my Canadian passport.

According [this site](https://tnvisaexpert.com/articles/forgot-to-return-i94/) I need:

> Turn in your I-94 Departure Record and documentation that you left the
>   United States to:
>
> (for UPS/Fedex)
>
> Coleman Data Solutions 3043
>
> Sanitarium Road Suite 2 Akron,
>
> OH 44312 DHS - CBP SBU

Is this information still correct?

From other side if I look at [my Travel history](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/history-search), I see the following:

> 2018-07-31 Departure ATL

So US Immigration knows that I left US.

Do they still need my I-94 record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customs and Border Protection has the same address on [their site](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/752/~/i-still-have-my-i-94), so it seems that the address is still correct.

However, since the US recorded your departure you can be unconcerned about sending in the form.  Its only purpose of to record your exit, and that already happened.

But if you're prone to worry, there's no harm in sending it in, either.